# Include code in getter while using Criteria + projection

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am having this getter in an Entity :

```
    public String getEmpType() {
    return empType == null ? "EMP" : empType;
}
```

and I am using Criteria + projection in the Dao :

`Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("employeeKey",key)) 
 .setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("empType")));`

Now I want to apply the same rule in getter (i.e. if empType is `null` set it to `EMP`) without duplicating the code here  .. is there a way to do so ?
i.e I want the `Criteria` to use the getter in the entity
note : I am using hibernate 3.1.0

Comment: Stupid question why can empType be null when it obviously has a default value?

Comment: thanks for your politeness ... actually this is (legacy code + business rules + DB data format )which has been changing over 10 years , so answering your question requires much discussion which is not appropriate here, but u can just cut it short and accept my answer (legacy code that I can't change now)

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with a static method that you can use in both cases like

```
public class EmpTypeHelper {

    public static String getEmpTypeOrDefault(String emptType) {
        return empType == null ? "EMP" : empType;
    }
}
```

Comment: defining a static method was the first answer that came to my mind actually .. but I was curious if I can tune hibernate to use the getter in criteria  (or something similar) instead of the field itself

Comment: No because the getter is bound to an object instance and is not static